# Android Market and Google Playstore search issue

Tags: android, google-play

I thought that I understand this right and that Android Market is gone, but it seams I'm wrong. Apparently one of my customers has old Android devices (I have no information how old), and on those devices they still have Android Market app, not Google play.

The problem is that he is not able to find app that we created and placed on the store in "Android Market" while it is visible and working in Google Play, and we can all see links on Google playstore.

Is the "Android Market" app really still the only available app for some Android devices?

Our app is designed to work from Android 2.2. and higher, so that might be the case if there is still Android Market, but If I search google the only information I get is that Android Marketplace is renamed to Google Playstore, so I can't find proper information if Android Market App is still working, if it is working on which devices is working?

Tnx.

Edit:
I got now info from customer that on device running HTC Sense 2.1 and Android 2.3.3. they can see the App in Android Market, but get the error: "Package file was not signed correctly".

At the same time on my device, running Android 2.2. and with google playstore removed, I'm able to download the app through Android Market and install it without problems.

Comment: as i know it's still working on some devices like htc wildfire - the first version. I was testing a few days ago an app on that device and it was still with the first version of market which i've seen (the green one). So i guess there are still some devices with that version of android market.

Comment: What android version of the device are they running on? If it's less than 2.2 they won't see your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that hey could still be running Android Market. Old custom roms, or people who never chose to accept updates.

If this person can't find your app, they must be on an older OS version, a device that you have blacklisted, a screen size that you don't support, or a country that you have not enabled.

There is still a [3-4% share of people running < version 2.2](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), so it's quite likely.